# Trig, derivative of $\sin x$, method used?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

[image: computation of the derivative of the sine]

How does one transform $\sin (x+h) - \sin x$ into $2\cos\bigl(\frac{1}{2}(x+h+x)\bigr)\cdot \sin\bigl(\frac{1}{2}(x+h-x)\bigr)$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint

use the [Prosthaphaeresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis) formula:
$$
\cos a \sin b=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin(a+b)-\sin(a-b) \right]
$$

(with $a=\frac{x+h}{2}+\frac{x}{2}$ and $b=\frac{x+h}{2}-\frac{x}{2}$)

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm interested to know where I'm wrong.

Comment: Such a situation has happened to me 3 times these last months, each time for a fully correct solution. It is very irritating.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:$$\sin { x-\sin { y } =2\sin { \frac { x-y }{ 2 }  } \cos { \frac { x+y }{ 2 }  }  } $$